# How can I map a "select all" query with 2 tables using SqlQuery

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity

I'm trying to retrieve all fields from two joined tables to any kind of a c# object.

So I'm trying to run this code:

```
var query = @$"EXEC('select *
   from persons p join students s on p.id=s.id 
   where p.id = 21')";

var result = _context.Database.SqlQuery<?>(query).ToList();
```

But I don't get what should be instead of the question mark.

I've tried `List<object>` and `Dictionary<string,string>` but since I couldn't get exactly how this is being mapped, I don't understand to what it can be mapped.

There is a somewhat similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30771552/using-sqlquerydictionarystring-string-in-entity-framework-6) but its solution only addresses two columns, and it apparently doesn't support returning nulls.

Comment: The generic type refers to the type of each of the returned objects. The `select *` probably won't help the data mapper, look at [this](https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/49989681/entity-framework-6-is-not-mapping-my-columns-correctly-using-attributes).

Comment: Wait, the post you linked seems to fit very well for you, what is the problem (except for nulls)?

Comment: Your ? is a Known Type. So you are working with Strongly Types here and should know your SqlQuery fields to be mapped in a known Entity Type. You can try dynamic types but not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a stored procedure or a function in the SQL level.
Then, just select then generated table / result.
So, you already have an idea of what class it is.

Answer (score 0):

I frequently use the dynamic type like this :

```
  var lst =   _context.Database.SqlQuery<dynamic>(query).ToList();  
  foreach (var item in lst)
  {
     var myVar = item.myfieldName;
  }
```

It may be preferable to name each field in your query instead of using select *.

Comment: That doesn't work.. It just returns an object which I cannot cast to anything..

Comment: it should return a collection of type <dynamic> that you can itterate through and for each item you can access every field of the query by item.fieldname syntax.

Comment: if you need to return the result, you can Serialize it with JSonConvert : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_context.Database.SqlQuery<dynamic>(query).ToList() );